# Load new content in Fancybox on Fancybox onClosed event

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I'm stuck with a problem with Fancybox windows. I use fancybox to display the content of a hidden div on my page (".popup" fancybox below). In that content, there is a link to a new fancybox content called #exemple. When I click on the link in the first fancybox, it loads the second fancybox content (iframe - this works fine). But I'd like to come back to the first fancybox when the user hits the close button of the second fancybox.

I tried with "onClosed" event but it doesn't work ...

Is there a way to do that?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Here is the code I use :

```
$("#exemple").fancybox({
    'width'             : '100%',
    'height'            : '100%',
    'titleShow'         : true,
    'titlePosition'     : 'over',
    'titleFormat'       : formatTitle,
    'autoScale'         : false,
    'centerOnScroll'    : true,
    'type'              : 'iframe',
    'onClosed'          : function() {
            alert('test');
            $(".popup").trigger('click');
        } 
});

$(".popup").fancybox({
    'autoScale'         : false,
    'centerOnScroll'    : true
});

// and here is the HTML code to trigger the hidden div:
<a style="font-weight: bold;" href=#data class=popup>our data</a>

//and the HTML code of the link inside the hidden div that gets displayed in the fancybox:
<a id=exemple title="xxx" href=xxx.php?id=xxx>link</a>
```

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 5):

I was working with same thing and onClosed was not working. After lots of research I figured out that there is some kind of versioning problem and onClosed works in older versions of fancy box. The other approach, which worked for me, is as following using beforeClose instead of onClosed.

‘beforeClose’: function() { alert(‘test’) },

This might be helpful for some of the readers.

Comment: This worked for me, +1, please note that when copying and pasting the above code the apostrophe gets copied as a single-quote, so re-type the apostrophes to avoid javascript errors

Comment: You can also use 'afterClose': function () {alert('test')}. I hope it will work the same way.

Answer (score 4):

It would help if you had a jsFiddle to work from, but first try wrapping the `onClosed` function code in a `setTimeout`. A zero time should be sufficient:

```
'onClosed' : function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".popup").trigger('click');
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Waouu, it works! Thanks a lot, you're a genius. What would be the solution if I wanted to update the fancybox content instead of closing en re-opening it?

Comment: Huh? Is that really working? What is the concept behind this one? I see it as a hack right now.

Comment: It's not really a hack... it's a work around. The cleanup function is called when the animation has completed. There is a [jquery bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7157) with the animation callback being called prematurely and the method to work around it is to use a setTimeout with zero time.

Comment: Though it isn't the exact question or the exact answer I wanted, but this setTimeout was a big big big hint and I finished off a problem that was killing me for two days. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
'onClosed'=> 'js:function() { alert("test") }',
```

note : we need to put "js:"

i m calling fancybox automatically (using extension)

It is Working fine for me