# How do I correctly use Fancybox's onClose property?

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I'm trying to update the shopping cart of my site upon closing a Fancybox instance.  I'm using Fancybox 1.3.4.  Assuming my function is valid, shouldn't the following work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () { 
    $("a.ProductRollover").fancybox({     
       'padding':0,
       'width': 785,
       'height': 554,
       'autoScale': false,
       'type': 'iframe',
       'onClosed': function() {
           $('#cart_total').html(json['total']);
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't spot anything wrong. Have you tried doing a simple alert() inside your onClosed function?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11920579/266644

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using onClosed use beforeClose or afterClose. Find the API documentation under the Callbacks tab here http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs.

Moreover, answer by [Mottie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145346/mottie) over here [Load new content in Fancybox on Fancybox onClosed event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799920/load-new-content-in-fancybox-on-fancybox-onclosed-event) might be helpful.